# How does java compiler know of generics type information of a code in jar?

Tags: java

I have a quetion regrading the java generics.
As I know,generic information is only available at compile time , through a process called "type erasure" all TYPE information 
goes away once the code is compiled and .class file is made

that is once .java file is compiled ,  List myList = new arrayList(), is what the .class file bytecode have, even though the list is declared as list of strings in .java file.

Having said that, consider below scenario.

I have a jar with a method with signature

```
public void check(List<String> p)
```

When I call this method from another code , the compiler enforces that the argument to check method should be `List<String>` only, nothing else.

Now since the check method exists in jar (.class files), how does compiler know about TYPE information required for `List<String>`, if TYPE information 
is already REMOVED when .class file is made ?

Comment: Your question does not contain a single example of a generic...?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Type erasure does not erase all information related to generics. Simply put, signature of the method in question (`public void check(List<String> p)`) is preserved in full detail. 
The preserved information can be obtained at run-time with reflection API (like  [`getGenericParameterTypes()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#getGenericParameterTypes%28%29), [`getTypeParameters()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#getTypeParameters%28%29) & others methods).

Comment: +1 There is generic information in the `class` file for the compiler to use, it's the JVM which doesn't use it (except for reflection)

Comment: @Piotr , so it is like the type information is available in .class files, JVM doesn't use it, as Peter has indicated.